# How to link UK BNF code to a chemical code (pubchem ID or CAS Number)?

Tags: health-informatics, public-health, chemical

Is there any way to link a United Kingdom BNF code of drug treatment to some kind of chemical compound ID, such as a PubChem ID or a CAS Number? I've got thousands of BNF codes (with descriptions) that I need to tally up with its chemical data. At the moment, it's slow progress doing it by hand by using the name of the drug and searching in PubChem.

Comment: You can probably go from BNF to SNOMED_CT with the spreadsheet available [here](https://www.nhsbsa.nhs.uk/prescription-data/understanding-our-data/bnf-snomed-mapping). You can use the UMLS Metathesaurus to go from SNOMED_CT go to RXNorm. From RXNorm CUI go to the active ingredient RXNorm CUI. Then from the active ingredient go from RXNorm to UNII ID. Finally, UNII is in PubChem. Most of these databases have full bulk download options and web APIs. The Methathesaurus, however, is a giant pain because you have to run a binary program to build the files.

Comment: @IanCampbell that's extremely helpful. Thank you.